# Restoring GRUB?

Tags: 12.10, grub2, restore

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

I primarily use Ubuntu 12.10, however I recently installed the beta of Fedora 18 to test it out. GRUB was replaced with the "fedora 18 grub" which looks slightly different. How do I restore the version of GRUB that comes with Ubuntu?

Comment: You can still run Ubuntu, yes? Try this one: "sudo grub-install –root-directory=/mnt/ /dev/sda" but w/out quotes and do note change to proper device. The /dev/sda is just an example.

Comment: @Marky can you provide a real answer instead of a comment. It would be better for the OP and the community?

Answer (score 0):

Try `update-grub` if that doesn't work then install the grub again using the **grub-install** command . It should detect Ubuntu automatically and include Ubuntu in the boot menu.

Comment: Thanks, but I used boot-repair

Answer (score 0):

yes you can restore the Ubuntu grub

1- update the Ubuntu grub

for doing this

> update-grub2

2 - then reboot the pc now you can find Ubuntu grub